# Texture size varying while repeating based on Mapping

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am new to blender and trying to use image textures. I am using Mapping to repeat the image texture on a surface. I need to apply the image texture to faces with different size. The face is actually a floor surface. The problem is that if I try to apply same material I end up different sized tiles. Is there anyway I can use one material and keep the size of tiles same across faces with different size ?
This is the material I am trying to use.
[image]

This is how the surfaces look.

[image]

Here the same material is used for 4 different faces. Each face has different sized tile.

Is there a better way to repeat the texture?

Note: I am using blender 2.9

Comment: is it the same object or is it seveeral objects using the same textures? In principled when you unwrap it should keep the proportions, unless these are different objects

Comment: These are different objects. Each surface is different plane.There are other objects in the picture which are making it look like a single contiguous plane.

Comment: so maybe select them all in Object mode, go in Edit mode, and unwrap? This way it should preserve the proportions

Comment: Thank you !! That works.

Comment: Otherwise you can instead of the UV coordinates,try using the Object coordinates, and use the Box projection mode inside your Texture node instead of flat

Comment: As I am new, it took a while to understand. This works too. Thank you !!